# is a long car ride safe for my newborn?

Tags: newborn

Im planning a trip from vermont to New York,  its about a 4 and a half hour trip and my babygirl is 1 month old. Im just worried she will get overwhelmed at being in the carseat so long, of course I will stop whenever necessary,  I breastfeed and dont use bottles yet. Im also worried she will get sick, or her body will be in pain or cramp from the same position so long. Is this a safe trip and what other things should I do to ensure she will be okay??

Comment: Related: http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14193/how-long-should-my-newborn-baby-be-in-a-car-seat

Comment: Personally,I think that the fact you need to stop more often in order to breastfeed and change the baby will probably give all the breaks the child needs. My guy had to make a few 8-hour (not including stops) trips. I think they other question will have the answers you need, but I always emphasize making sure you have extra changes of clothes and burp-clothes, and anything you'd need to clean up spit up. Although, the younger my son was the more likely he was to just sleep through the ride.

Answer (score 0):

In some respects it's not great for them, but at that age they sleep a lot and can't turn over so the length of journey isn't per-se a problem though regular long journeys can present some risk factors...

Stackexchange question [How long should my newborn baby be in a car seat](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/14193/how-long-should-my-newborn-baby-be-in-a-car-seat) covers the main areas.

Since that question was answered and accepted there has been a correlation with long journeys and increases in cases of flat head syndrome ([Plagiocephaly](http://www.babycenter.com/0_plagiocephaly-flat-head-syndrome_1187981.bc)) and new advice relating to reducing the risk of [cot death in car seats](http://www.dbh.nhs.uk/Car_seat_awareness.aspx) especially where the car seat doubles as a buggy/stroller.